# QBasic: how to run a program from within another program?

Tags: qbasic, qb64

I have made two different programs in QBasic and they both are saved in different .bas files, i.e one is **1.bas** and the other **2.bas**.

How to open program **1.bas** while I am in program **2.bas**, without closing it?

Program 1 should run inside program 2 for some time, and when it ends I should again be in program 2. Is there any way to do that?

I would like to know if there is a syntax for this that works in QBasic and/or QB64.

Comment: It is 2016. People are still writing code in qbasic?

Comment: we are force to use it in school level

Comment: @trincot that i also know but answer according to my question

Comment: @trincot i understand anyway which programming language will be best to learn in your point of view

Comment: @trincot you use facebook or twitter

Comment: @trincot nope thanks for that.

Comment: @trincot sir you use any social meia

Comment: @trincot so i cant contact you later if necessary

Comment: @trincot you use twitter

Comment: @trincot sorry for my rude comment f before i am only 13 years and i dont know that i am talking with such big ad great person

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Qbasic you can use `CHAIN` command to pass control to another .BAS file and when it is finished it will return to the first .BAS file. You can combine it with `COMMON` to also share variables between the two programs.

You could also use `RUN` but in QBasic you can't pass variables (not sure but I think the control will not return). And in QB64 it *is* possible to pass variables using `RUN`

See the standard COM1_EX.BAS and COM2_EX.BAS as an example, contents of COM1_EX.BAS:

```
' == COM1_EX.BAS - COMMON statement programming example ==
DIM Values(1 TO 50)
COMMON Values(), NumValues

PRINT "Enter values one per line. Type 'END' to quit."
NumValues = 0
DO
   INPUT "-> ", N$
   IF I >= 50 OR UCASE$(N$) = "END" THEN EXIT DO
   NumValues = NumValues + 1
   Values(NumValues) = VAL(N$)
LOOP
PRINT "Leaving COM1_EX.BAS to chain to COM2_EX.BAS"
PRINT "Press any key to chain... "
DO WHILE INKEY$ = ""
LOOP

CHAIN "com2_ex"
```

contents of COM2_EX.BAS:

```
' == COM2_EX.BAS - COMMON statement programming example ==
' Notice that the variables Values() and NumValues from COM1_EX
' will be called X() and N here in COM2_EX
DIM X(1 TO 50)
COMMON X(), N

PRINT
PRINT "Now executing file com2_ex.bas, reached through a CHAIN command"
IF N > 0 THEN
   Sum = 0
   FOR I = 1 TO N
      Sum = Sum + X(I)
   NEXT I
   PRINT "The average of the values is"; Sum / N
END IF
```